# Is it possible to use jQuery slimbox2 to display divs with text instead of images?

Tags: jquery-plugins, html, modal-dialog, lightbox

Hi I'm trying to get some text content to display in a modal / lightbox type window when a link is clicked. I chose slimbox2 because it's lightweight, but it seems to be intended solely for displaying images and image galleries.

Is there anyway to get it to display a Div when a link is clicked?
OR can anyone recommend a plugin that will do what I need?

Thanks all

Here's my code:

```
var sidetwos = $('div.side2');
var fliplinks = $('a.flip');

fliplinks.each(function(index, object) {
        $(this).click(function() {
            $(sidetwos[index]).fancybox();
        });
    });
```

Comment: I wasn't getting anywhere with slimbox2 so I've decided to try http://fancybox.net/. I've managed to get the modal content window to display, but it ignores the css defined for the content in the parent pages css file! Any suggestions please?

Comment: Solved it, the styles weren't getting applied because the parent container was being replaced with the modal window wrapepr. Works great now, and at 6kb(compressed) it's only a fraction bigger than slimbox2 (4kb compressed)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well nobody else is likely to pick this up so I'll post my solution...

I decided to use the [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/) jQuery plugin (as I mentioned in my comment) which made things a lot easier!

I have a series of 'Business card' type DIVs displaying a logo and some contact details with a link for more info. The link is attached to the fancybox js call, with the information DIVs grouped using the `rel=` gallery reference to allow navigating between them without having open and close the modal box for each one!

HTML:

```
<a href="#offerDescription-$id" class="flip" rel="offer-description">Show Details &raquo;</a>

<div id="offerDescription-$id" class="lightbox">
    <img class="offerlogo" src="http://www.everyone-benefits.co.uk/images/logos/$logo.jpg" />
    <h2>$Title</h2>
    <p class="description">$Text</p>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() { // jQuery 'domready' shorthand
    $('a.flip[rel=offer-description]').fancybox();
});
```

Without meaning to be patronising:

Please note that the `$` notation used in the HTML part is only to imply that the information is comming from PHP and does not represent actual PHP code!